# Reset global variable that I use as counter

Tags: javascript

I want to reset to 0 a global variable.
Is that a correct way if I want to use-and-reuse a counter?

```
var myCounter = 0;

function increaseValue(){
  // Code that increase "myCounter"
}

function resetGlobal(){
  // The code needed to reset myCounter to "0"
}

function onClickTrigger() {
  if (myCounter < 10) {
    increaseValue();
    // Other blocks of code
  } else if (myCounter == 10) {
    resetGlobal();
    // Other blocks of code
  }      
}
```

With **onClickTrigger** I can increment the value of **myCounter** each time I click on it, then, when the counter reach **10** it stops. My question is about how to reset the new value of **myCounter** from **10** to **0** to start again. It's like a loop made by click.

Comment: so did you try setting it to zero?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set global variable in JQuery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645241/how-to-set-global-variable-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The below is a working example of what you're trying to do. Because myCounter is already in the global scope, you just need to pass a new value into it and that be reflected throughout the code.

I've used an ES6 variable declaration ([let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)) rather than var. The first function is your counter, and will just pass i back to myCounter until it hits 10.

To reset, all you need to do is set the resetGlobal function to pass 0 as a value back to myCounter

```
 let myCounter = 0;

 function increaseValue(){
  for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
       myCounter = i
  }};

 function resetGlobal(){
  myCounter = 0
 };
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted when it is a working solution to the question?